# Using a CDate in a Countifs function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif, date-conversion

I was wondering if there was a way to use the CDate function in a countif statement? I'm trying to find dates less than 2 weeks old, am and currently using this statement:

```
=COUNTIF(CDATE(Table1[Date Closed]),">=" &TODAY() - 14)
```

I need to turn the Date Closed of the table into actual dates without changing the table (right now they're in the format 13-Mar-2018 but as text format).

Is there a way to do this within the Countif function or am I going to have to do a a VBA code to first change the dates?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried spreadsheet function [DATEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) istead of the `VBA` function `CDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATEVALUE(Table1[TextDates])>=(TODAY()-14)))
```

[image]

*Although I do wonder why you can't have dates as real Excel dates, rather than text strings*

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your table and insert a column (you could hide the original or place the new column at the end or next to the original) and convert the text date to a date via the DATEVALUE() function.
   See reference:
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252
2. You may want to apply format to the new cell/column to look like a date.
3. Set up your table for "Using structured references with Excel tables."
   See reference:
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e
4. Count dates based on your condition. 
   See reference:
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-numbers-or-dates-based-on-a-condition-976d0074-245d-49e6-bf5f-1207983f82ed

[image]